# JSON Parse from LocalStorage error

Tags: javascript, json

I am storing an object in localStorage using the following

```
function onExit(){
   localStorage.setItem("my_object","'" + JSON.stringify(object) + "'");
 }
```

When logging this out of localStorage it looks like this

```
'{"date":"2016-05-31T23:00:00.000Z","Name":"name","Code":"code","required":"false"}'
```

Now if I call JSON.parse on this directly it works, that is to say

```
JSON.parse('{"date":"2016-05-31T23:00:00.000Z","Name":"name","Code":"code","required":"false"}')
```

will give me an object. But if I try

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.my_object)
```

I get the 'unexpected character at line 1 of JSON data' error message

Where am I going wrong? Note: I have tried not enclosing the object in single quotes to no effect.

Comment: works for me... are you certain you don't have a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to wrap JSON.stringify(object) with the extra quotes (`"'"`) as it returns a usable string.

```
localStorage.setItem("my_object",JSON.stringify(object));
```

To retrive and decode the JSON object, you need to call `getItem`

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("my_object"))
```

Comment: Yes, I was missing getItem cheers. Will accept when it lets me!

Answer (score 4):

Either, save your object without quotes i.e.

```
function onExit(){
   localStorage.setItem("my_object",JSON.stringify(object));
 }
```

Or, if you do not remove quotes while saving, then you need to remove the enclosing quotes before trying to parse the object.